# gettimeofday calculates the runtime, with occasional significant deviations?

Tags: c, linux, arm, linux-device-driver

I use `gettimeOfday` to calculate the code execution time, The `ReadData` function consists of two parts: reading `/dev/spiio0` and reading/writing
`SPI`. The test execution time for `ReadData` is `Timer`, the test reading time for `/dev/spiio0` is `Timer1`, and the test reading time for `SPI` is `Timer2`. In theory, `Timer≈(approximately equal to)Timer1+Timer2`, but there are occasional occurrences of `Timer>>(far greater than)Timer1+Timer2`. My current question is why is there a situation where `Timer>>(far greater than)Timer1+Timer2`?

When I switched to testing with the `clock_gettime` function, the same goes for me.

---

For example, pseudocode:

```
function A 
{
     operation B;
     operation C;
}
```

The execution time of test function A should be approximately equal to the sum of the execution times of operation B and operation C, but in reality, there may be situations where it is much longer than the sum of times.

---

Abnormal time:

```
timer1 = 8242 us
timer2 = 440 us
timer = 95027 us
```

main.c:

```
#include "spidev.h"
#include <poll.h>
#include <time.h>

int SpiDevFd = 0;

struct _SPI_Settings spi_settings;

uint8_t tx[256] = {0};
uint8_t rx[256] = {0};

int ReadData(int fd)
{
        int ret = 0;
        char ch = 0;

        struct timeval start1; 
        struct timeval end1;
        unsigned long timer1 = 0;
        gettimeofday(&start1, NULL);
        ret = read(fd, &ch, sizeof(ch));
        gettimeofday(&end1, NULL);
        timer1 = 1000000 * (end1.tv_sec - start1.tv_sec) + end1.tv_usec - start1.tv_usec;
        printf("timer1 = %ld us\n", timer1);


        if (ret) {
                struct timeval start2;
                struct timeval end2;
                unsigned long timer2 = 0;
                gettimeofday(&start2, NULL);
                TransferSpi(SpiDevFd, &spi_settings, tx, sizeof(tx), rx);
                gettimeofday(&end2, NULL);
                timer2 = 1000000 * (end2.tv_sec - start2.tv_sec) + end2.tv_usec - start2.tv_usec;
                printf("timer2 = %ld us\n", timer2);
                hex_dump(rx, ARRAY_SIZE(rx), 32, "RX");
                return 0;
        }
        exit(-1);
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    int fd = open("/dev/spiio0", O_RDONLY);
    if (fd < 0) {
        perror("Failed to open GPIO value file\n");
        return 1;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i <= 255; i++)
    {
        tx[i] = i;
    }

        spi_settings.mode = 0;
        spi_settings.bits = 8;
        spi_settings.speed = 10*1000*1000;
        spi_settings.delay = 0;
        SpiDevFd = OpenSpiDev("/dev/spidev2.0", &spi_settings);
    if (SpiDevFd < 0) {
                perror("Failed to spi dev file\n");
                return 1;
        }
        unsigned long max = 0;
        unsigned long min = 8500;
        unsigned long avg = 0;
        int testCnt = 10000;
        for (int i = 0; i < testCnt; i++) {
                struct timeval start;
                struct timeval end;
                unsigned long timer = 0;
                gettimeofday(&start, NULL);
                int ret = ReadData(fd);
                gettimeofday(&end, NULL);
                timer = 1000000 * (end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) + end.tv_usec - start.tv_usec;
                printf("timer = %ld us\n", timer);
                avg += timer;
                if (timer > max) {
                        max = timer;
                        if (max > 25000) {
                                printf("max ===%ld\n", max);
                                exit(-1);
                        }
                }
                if (timer < min) {
                        min = timer;
                }
        }
        printf("max=%ld us,min=%ld us, avg= %ld us\n", max, min, avg/testCnt);

    close(fd);
    return 0;
}
```

spidev.c:

```
#include "spidev.h"
#include <linux/spi/spidev.h>
#include <linux/types.h>
#include <getopt.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>

#define SPI_API_VERSION "v1.0.0-a1"

enum
{
        SPI_MODE = 0,
        SPI_DELAY = 0,
        SPI_SPEED = 15 * 1000 * 1000,
        SPI_BITS = 8
};

int TransferSpi(int fd, SPI_Settings *pspiSettings, const uint8_t *tx, int txSize, uint8_t *rx)
{

        int ret;

        struct spi_ioc_transfer tr = {
                .tx_buf = (unsigned long)tx,
                .rx_buf = (unsigned long)rx,
                .len = txSize,
                .delay_usecs = pspiSettings->delay,
                .speed_hz = pspiSettings->speed,
                .bits_per_word = pspiSettings->bits,
        };
        ret = ioctl(fd, SPI_IOC_MESSAGE(1), &tr);
        if (ret < 1)
        {
                perror("can't send spi message");
                if (errno == EAGAIN) {
                        printf("spi operation would block, try a gain later.\n");
                }
                return -1;
        }
        return ret;
}

int OpenSpiDev(const char *devName, SPI_Settings *pspiSettings)
{
        printf("the version of spi api is %s.\n", SPI_API_VERSION);
        int fd = -1;
        int ret = -1;
        fd = open(devName, O_RDWR);
        if (fd < 0)
        {
                perror("can't open device");
                return -1;
        }
        /*
         * spi mode
         */
        ret = ioctl(fd, SPI_IOC_WR_MODE, &pspiSettings->mode);
        if (ret == -1)
        {
                perror("can't set spi mode");
                return -1;
        }

        ret = ioctl(fd, SPI_IOC_RD_MODE, &pspiSettings->mode);
        if (ret == -1)
        {
                perror("can't get spi mode");
                return -1;
        }

        /*
         * bits per word
         */
        ret = ioctl(fd, SPI_IOC_WR_BITS_PER_WORD, &pspiSettings->bits);
        if (ret == -1)
        {
                perror("can't set bits per word");
                return -1;
        }

        ret = ioctl(fd, SPI_IOC_RD_BITS_PER_WORD, &pspiSettings->bits);
        if (ret == -1)
        {
                perror("can't get bits per word");
                return -1;
        }

        /*
         * max speed hz
         */
        ret = ioctl(fd, SPI_IOC_WR_MAX_SPEED_HZ, &pspiSettings->speed);
        if (ret == -1)
        {
                perror("can't set max speed hz");
                return -1;
        }

        ret = ioctl(fd, SPI_IOC_RD_MAX_SPEED_HZ, &pspiSettings->speed);
        if (ret == -1)
        {
                perror("can't get max speed hz");
                return -1;
        }
        int flags = fcntl(fd, F_GETFL);
        if (fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, flags|O_NONBLOCK) == -1) {
                perror("can't set non-blocking mode");
                return -1;
        }
        printf("spi delay: %d\n", pspiSettings->delay);
        printf("spi mode: %d\n", pspiSettings->mode);
        printf("bits per word: %d\n", pspiSettings->bits);
        printf("max speed: %d Hz (%d KHz)\n", pspiSettings->speed, pspiSettings->speed / 1000);
        return fd;
}

void CloseSpiDev(const int fd)
{
        close(fd);
}

void hex_dump(const void *src, size_t length, size_t line_size,
                                         char *prefix)
{
        int i = 0;
        const unsigned char *address = src;
        const unsigned char *line = address;
        unsigned char c;

        printf("%s | ", prefix);
        while (length-- > 0)
        {
                printf("%02X ", *address++);
                if (!(++i % line_size) || (length == 0 && i % line_size))
                {
                        if (length == 0)
                        {
                                while (i++ % line_size)
                                        printf("__ ");
                        }
                        printf(" |");
                        while (line < address)
                        {
                                c = *line++;
                                printf("%c", (c < 32 || c > 126) ? '.' : c);
                        }
                        printf("|\n");
                        if (length > 0)
                                printf("%s | ", prefix);
                }
        }
}

int test_main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        SPI_Settings spiSettings = {SPI_MODE, SPI_BITS, SPI_SPEED, SPI_DELAY};
        int fd = OpenSpiDev("/dev/spidev2.0", &spiSettings);

        uint8_t tx[256] = {0};
        for (int i = 0; i <= 255; i++)
        {
                tx[i] = i;
        }
        uint8_t rx[ARRAY_SIZE(tx)] = {
                0,
        };
        struct timeval start;
        struct timeval end;
        unsigned long timer;
        gettimeofday(&start, NULL);

        TransferSpi(fd, &spiSettings, tx, ARRAY_SIZE(tx), rx);

        gettimeofday(&end, NULL);
        timer = 1000000 * (end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) + end.tv_usec - start.tv_usec;
        printf("timer = %ld us\n", timer);
        hex_dump(tx, ARRAY_SIZE(tx), 32, "TX");
        hex_dump(rx, ARRAY_SIZE(rx), 32, "RX");

        CloseSpiDev(fd);

        return 0;
}
```

spidev.h:

```
#ifndef __SPIDEV_H
#define __SPIDEV_H

#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/time.h>


#define ARRAY_SIZE(a) (sizeof(a) / sizeof((a)[0]))

typedef struct _SPI_Settings
{
    uint8_t mode;   /*recommendation value: 0*/
    uint8_t bits;   /*recommendation value: 8*/
    uint32_t speed; /*recommendation value: 15*1000*1000*/
    uint16_t delay; /*recommendation value: = 0*/
} SPI_Settings;

int TransferSpi(int fd, SPI_Settings *pspiSettings, const uint8_t *tx, int txSize, uint8_t *rx);
int OpenSpiDev(const char *devName, SPI_Settings *pspiSettings);
void CloseSpiDev(const int fd);

void hex_dump(const void *src, size_t length, size_t line_size, char *prefix);
#endif //__SPIDEV_H
```

Comment: What hardware are you using? While valid, the use of `start` and `end` struct both in `main` and in `ReadData` is a bit awkward. Running on a microcontroller there can be significant timing differences between calls to `read` based on whatever else your system is doing at the time. Measuring the time read takes to read a byte will likely result in measuring more OS scheduling delay than actual read-time which can vary significantly around such a small measurement. It will help to know what you are running this on.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin `ARM v7`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Adding execution time checks to both the `main` and `ReadData` functions is because when I only measure the execution time of `ReadData`, I found that there is occasionally a large time jump. Therefore, I want to locate which link in the `ReadData` function caused the time exception.

Comment: Arm v7 - is this a Raspberry Pi running Pi OS or the like? I can see the time in both places as a check. Remember `read` will block waiting on data on `"/dev/spiio0"`. That can also inject variability into your timings. SPI makes use of both hi and low bus states and I'm not sure how read will respond waiting on data there. If we know which OS we can check further. Also, look at the kernel [SPI documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.14/driver-api/spi.html). That's what I'd have to do. It will be from the driver side, but will tell you what is happening.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin  Allwinner A40i，with kernel 3.10.

Comment: That's a neat board. 4 SPI controllers. The kernel documentation I linked to is 4.4, but the SPI interface should be the same between the two. What is the ultimate goal? Measuring how long it takes to read a byte seems like symptom for another problem. Largely how long it takes to read a byte is irrelevant -- it takes however long it takes and the code should be designed around that fact, and the fact it may return 0 bytes read if none are ready depending on how blocking is configured, polling, etc.. If you have `epoll` (or `pselect`) you may look at that to control a timeout for the read.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin The time it takes to read `/dev/spiio0` and the time it takes to read SPI  is normal, but I just don't know where this large 'timer=95027 us' comes from and what causes it to be so outrageous?

Comment: Your times shown are 8 ms, .4 ms, and 95 ms. What is it that is being sent over SPI that you are attempting to read? Just pointing `read` at `/dev/spiio0` doesn't mean there is anything there ready to be read. Are you sure the SPI communications are stable at 10 MHz? It's hard to say without some type of trace. Also what about 5-10K pull-ups on CS and MISO. If your SPI communication isn't stable and the bus is just floating, it isn't surprising that read can widely vary in the time it takes to read a bite from the bus.

Comment: This question may be better asked on [Electronics StackExchange](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/) as the SPI expertise is there. The question is a bit awkward here as it isn't a direct programming problem. I've had good luck with questions like this there. Worth a try.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I am even more confused now, and I don't quite understand why you keep emphasizing the issues of `/dev/spiio` and `SPI`? The time for reading `/dev/spiio` and reading `SPI` is already very clear. They are `8ms` and `0.4ms`, and they are only a part of the `95ms`. I am just curious where the remaining `86ms` come from now?

Comment: what does the scope show?

Comment: @old_timer Sorry, what scope are you referring to?

Comment: you are trying to measure a spi transaction yes?  and seeing a strange number from time to time?  do I understand?  what does the oscilloscope show for the spi transactions?  are any of them long and strange?

Comment: What @old_timer means by "scope" and what I mean by "trace" is what does your signal look like or an oscilloscope or logic analyzer. You are pointing `read()` at the SPI filesys device where transfers are normally handled by `ioctl()`. You are asking the question of why my byte read timings vary from 8, .4, and 95 ms? What we are asking is what does the signal on that device look like that may explain your delays. Is it a consistent, uniform SPI signal or is it a mess or random frequencies? Simply reading from `/dev/spiio` with `read()` isn't a normal thing to do.

Comment: While for a STM device, [Accessing SPI Devices in Linux](https://www.emcraft.com/som/stm32f7-212/accessing-spi-devices-in-linux) generally takes a similar form.

Comment: @old_timer Perhaps my previous question description was not clear enough. I am not testing `SPI` read and write time, but rather curious about why there is an occasional value that is much higher than the average during test execution?

Comment: @David C. Rankin Okay, thank you. Let me take a look.

Comment: @Vimer good, that is what my response was about then.

Comment: have you used an uncooked timer?

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that differences in `gettimeofday()` do not measure program execution time, but time passed in general. Hence, OS or other programs may have been running during a given interval and adding to the measured time. Since you mention, that the time difference is occasional, this could be the explanation.

With this reservation, let us look at what is measured:

- `timer1` measures read of 1 byte from SPI.
- `timer2` measures a SPI transfer in the unknown (does not matter) function TransferSpi.
- `timer` measures both of the above and additionally:

  - Reading of an additional byte from SPI.
  - Two `printf()` statements
  - Call to an unknown function `hex_dump()`
  - (a few expressions which likely have insignificant execution time and can be ignored in this context)

These additional items are by no means insignificant. I would not be surprised if the `printf()`-statements alone could explain the difference.

I would recommend measuring the above mentioned bullets separately which may show where the additional time is spent.

Comment: `timer1` measures read of 1 byte from `/dev/spiio0`.